# When does $n-2$ divide $2(n+1)(n-1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, integers

The question is in the title, where $n$ is an integer $\geq 4$.

I first tried to solve it by saying $n-2$ divides $2$, or $n+1$, or $n-1$. Then one finds $n=4,5$. But then I realized that there may be other solutions (for example $n=8$) whenever $n-2$ is not prime.

So, what is the good method to solve it?

Comment: See what remainder you get when you divide the polynomial $2(n+1)(n-1)$ by the polynomial $n-2$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Oh yes, I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\frac{2(n-1)(n+1)}{n-2}=\frac{2(n^2-4+3)}{n-2}=2(n+2)+\frac{6}{n-2},$$
which says $$n-2\in\{\pm6,\pm2,\pm3,\pm1\}$$ and with $n\geq4$ we can get all values of $n$.

Answer (score 3):

It is much easier if you mark $k=n-2$ and then ask when $k$ divide $2(k+1)(k+3) = 2k^2+8k+6$. Now this is clearly iff $k\mid 6$...